# Changing date format in php?

Tags: php, date, formatting

Currently I have a date format like this:

```
2012-07-24
```

I want to change it to this format:

```
July 07, 2012, Friday
```

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: have you tried something Please show us

Answer (score 3):

you can use any of following method:

```
//1
echo date('F d, Y, l',strtotime('2012-07-24'));
//2
$date = date_create('2012-07-24');
echo date_format($date, 'F d, Y, l');
//3
$date = new DateTime('2012-07-24');
echo $date->format('F d, Y, l');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
echo date("F d, Y, l");
```

Read this for more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_create_from_format`, then use `date_format`

```
date_format(date_create_from_format("2012-07-24","Y-m-d"),"F D, Y, l")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    function changedateformat($date)
{
    $date1=explode("-",$date);

    $mktime=mktime(0,0,0,$date1[1],$date1[2],$date1[0]);
    return date('F d, Y, l',$mktime);
}

$date1="2012-07-24";
echo changedateformat($date1);
?>
```